# Rotations of cube.

Tags: group-theory, rotations, symmetry, permutation-cycles

[Here](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/discrete/groups/categorise/finite/cube/index.htm) shows a cube with base touching face edges' vertices as: $\{3,7\},\{7,8\}, \{8,4\}, \{4,3\}.$

The opposite face has edges' vertices $\{1,2\},\{2,6\}, \{6,5\}, \{5,1\}.$

It states the below :

$$x = \text{rotation about } \,x = (1, 4, 8, 5) (2, 3, 7, 6)$$
$$y =\text{rotation about}\, y = (1, 5, 6, 2) (4, 8, 7, 3)$$
$$z = \text{rotation about}\, z = (1, 2, 3, 4) (5, 6, 7, 8)$$

Shouldn't be:
$$x = \text{rotation about }\, x = (1, 4) (8, 5) (2, 3) (7, 6)$$
$$y =\text{rotation about}\, y = (1, 5) (6, 2) (4, 8) (7, 3)$$
$$z = \text{rotation about} \,z = (1, 2)(3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider the square face $(1485)$. It requires a four-cycle for a rotation about the $x$-axis, since, otherwise, two disjoint two-cycles would have order two.

Such a rotation of the square is a rotation of the cube, provided you take into account the opposite square.

The other axes are similar.